# Refactoring C# code for conversion to a WPF application (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

For this guessing game, I want to refactor this glass cannon of a code for conversion to a WPF application. Any methods I could use to shorten this/successfully convert and tips on VS, in general, would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using the WPF app (core) as a template for this program. As well as using the Microsoft tutorial for it to build it. The UI for this project is mostly done, just need to import this code.

Do note I'm in high school so my scope of knowledge isn't that big.

EDIT: Ok.

1. Firstly what I want to do with this code is cutoff the needless "IF" and "console.write" statements for a clean solution.
2. Secoundly I'm seperating the solution into two files, an App.xaml.cs file and a MainWindow.Xaml.cs file. Within App.xaml file I'm putting all my public classes(ex:guess,rnd,etc). While the MainWindow.Xaml file is where I'm putting the "Game Logic".

What I've done so far is; in regards to MainWindow.xaml is two methods. A public method that initializes rnd ccalculations. And a "Button_Click" private method that once the user submits their guess the "game" sees if it matches and displays if they are right or wrong including how long it took them to guess corectly.

```
    class MainClass 
    {
     public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int ans = rnd.Next(1,10);
    Console.WriteLine("Pick an integer between 1 and 10");
    
    var num1 = Console.ReadLine();
    int v1 = Convert.ToInt32(num1);
     
    if(v1 == ans)
    {
      int count = 1;
      Console.WriteLine($"{v1} is correct. You Win!");
      Console.WriteLine($"It took you to {count} gues find the number {ans}." );
    }
    else
    {
      if(v1<ans){
        Console.WriteLine("To high");
      }
      else
      Console.WriteLine("To low");
      
      Console.WriteLine("Pick an interger between 1 and 10");
      Console.WriteLine($"{v1} isn't correct. Try again!");
      var num2 = Console.ReadLine();
      int v2 = Convert.ToInt32(num2);
        if(v2 == ans)
        {
          int count = 2;
          Console.WriteLine($"{v2} is correct. You Win!");
          Console.WriteLine($"It took you {count} gueses to find the number {ans}" );
        }
        else
        {
          if(v1<ans){
          Console.WriteLine("To high");
          }
          else
          Console.WriteLine("To low");
          
          Console.WriteLine("Pick an interger between 1 and 10");
          Console.WriteLine($"{v2} isn't correct. Try again!");
          var num3 = Console.ReadLine();
          int v3 = Convert.ToInt32(num3);
            if(v3 == ans)
            {
              int count = 3;
              Console.WriteLine($"{v3} is correct. You Win!");
              Console.WriteLine($"It took you {count} gueses to find the number {ans}" );
            }
            else
            {
              if(v1<ans){
              Console.WriteLine("To high");
              }
              else
              Console.WriteLine("To low");
              
              Console.WriteLine("Pick an interger between 1 and 10");
              Console.WriteLine($"{v3} isn't correct");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"You Lose! The correct number is {ans}. ");
        }
      }  
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi TheNijuu, welcome to SO! Asking for open-ended advice and refactoring doesn't usually get much of a response. I'd recommend doing a few things: 1) point out parts of your code you think is especially fragile or ugly, 2) describe what you think you need in order to convert and 3) MOST IMPORTANTLY: show us what you've already tried. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

So many things happening here, we would need a lot of time to explain.

Let me try to get to the basics. A class in C# is a blueprint of state and behavior.

In that term, you could model your code as a `GameRound`

```
public class GameRound {
    private int noOfTries;
    private int maxNoOfTries;
    private int correctNumber;
    private bool success;

    public bool HasRoundEnded { get {
        return maxNoOfTries == noOfTries;
      }
    }

    public bool Success { get {
        return success;
      }
    }

    public GameRound() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int ans = rnd.Next(1,10);
        correctNumber = ans;
    }

    public bool GuessSolution(int guess) {
        if (guess == correctNumber) {
            this.success = true;
        } else {
            this.success = false;
            maxNoOfTries++;
        }
        return this.success;
    }
```

You can see that most of your logic, was included in a class. I'll leave it to you to figure out how to use it.

You'll notice that there is no dependency on Console.Write or read. You can use that code in a console application or a UI or even a website. This happens because we separate the concerns of the class to only model a game round.

Another piece of advice, is for you to use a `while` loop with the class provided, to solve your problem in the console application. That way you'll understand how to use repeating structures and objects of classes.